# How to include an avatar/profile image in Django send_email with a "noreply" address?

Tags: django, email, django-templates

In email clients such as Gmail and Apple Mail, with each incoming email there's an avatar/profile image of the email's sender.

I have a Django app that sends emails from a "noreply@mycompany.com" email address using `send_mail`. The (sanitized) code looks something like the following:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from myapp.models import User

...

users = User.objects.all()
subject = 'Email for {name}'.format(name=user.name)
plaintext = get_template('emails/email_template.txt')
html = get_template('emails/email_template.html')
data = {'name': user.name}
text_content = plaintext.render(data)
html_content = html.render(data)
for user in users:
    send_mail(subject, text_content, 'noreply@mycompany.com', [user.email], html_message=html_content)
    print('Email sent: ' + user.email)
```

I want to have my company's logo be displayed in email clients as the avatar/profile image. What is the best way to accomplish this? For example, is this something I can specify in my emails' Django template?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can add your logo to the templates..

Comment: @Sumithran How can this logo be added, in django template syntax? Or is it just HTML -- in which case, what is the HTML I should add?

Comment: you just add an <img> tag having source reference to the static logo file in your Django template file, that's it.